# How to store a continuous stream of data so that you can access the most frequent values?

Tags: java, data-structures

A stream of stock updates are coming in the form of ticker, buy/sell pair (example YHOO,300) from the securities exchange(at a very high rate).  We have to always display the top 5 most traded stock by volume at any given point of time. How would you maintain these values in memory?

My idea is to use a hashmap(Ticker->Volume) to update our datastore from the feed O(1).And then create a Treemap based on the volume to display the top5 stocks O(1). But what I'm not able to come up is an efficient way to sync the Treemap data as the values in the hashmap change (very frequently) .
Any suggestions?

Comment: "We have to always display the top 5 most traded stock by volume at any given point of time" how long is your window? top five that day? top five in the last 30 seconds?

Comment: Top five at that particular instant(this keeps changing frequently). You can assume the windo is 1 sec.This is a live input stream.

Comment: so if you see 1000 trades of ABC 3 seconds ago and one trade of XYZ 1 second ago, you only want to display XYZ?

Comment: Its cumulative till the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of trades is an always increasing cumulative value (which it seems to be), you can just maintain:

- Your hashmap for updating the number of trades in O(1).
- A simple array of 5 elements representing the top 5 tickers along with their volume.

When a new update arrives, you update your hashmap in O(1) and, if the new number of trades is big enough to enter the top 5, you update also your array. Checking the array and updating it can be done in O(1). You can also use binary search if you don't want to compare the new volume with all 5 values.

You can't do much better than checking an average of log(5) values.

---

If the number of trades in not increasingly monotone (which seems unlikely, but can happen if you want to consider the number of trades done in a bounded interval of time), you can also maintain:

- Your hashmap (Ticker -> Volume) for saving the updates on ticker volumes.
- For the top 5, you need to use a heap sorted by decreasing volumes.

When an update arrives you will:

1. Get the previous value (if any) of the Volume for the ticker from the hashmap in O(1)
2. Remove the old value (if present) from the heap in O(log n), looking up by the old volume
3. Add the new value in the heap in O(log n)
4. Update the new value in the hashmap in O(1)

The total complexity is O(log n) where "n" is the number of tickers.

Even if you need the top 5 tickers, when the volume of one ticker goes down, you need to find the 6th element that will become 5th, and a 7th element .. and so on.
I don't think you can go much lower than O(log n) in the complexity if the number of trades is not monotone.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a heap data structure where the root is the most traded stock. Its child are the 2nd most traded ones. Root's grand children  will give the 4th and 5th

Comment: Updating the heap very frequently(since the feed is coming in at a very high rate) is not efficient.

Comment: Use two hashmaps.  One will take data from feed and the other will update treeMap or Heap every 'x' sec. Next 'x' sec switch the input feed to other hashmap etc ... REad always from heap / treemap .. Ofcourse the statistics  is delayed by 'x' seconds now

Answer (score 0):

These are the three options I can think of:

- Use a [bag](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) to collect the stock symbols and iterate through it occasionally to count the frequency. After the closing bell each day, reset the bag. This will work but I doubt you really want the stats a day at a time.
- I'm thinking you'll want a window around a minute to make this a really work. In that case I'd keep the trades in a [dequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html). Insert new trades in the front, trim old ones from the back. Freeze it occasionally to count the top five. This works, but if things heat up it might be hard to prodict how big of a queue you might need.
- An alternative approach is to use some sort of [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). But I'm not sure it is any better than just displaying the most recent five trades.

Answer (score 0):

Check following URLS:
*emphasized text*
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html?
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?